# Array functions map and foreach not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects in react native but some reason I can't do it.
This is what my array looks like.
[here is the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51LIQ.png)

When I try to map through this array with `arr.map((item,key) => console.log(item.id))` nothing happens in debugger.

Any help?

Edit2: This is the full function.

```
getPhotos = async () => {
        var firebaseStorageRef = await firebase.storage().ref();
        const photos = [];
        const documentSnapshot = await firestore()
            .collection('pictures')
            .doc(this.props.route.params.tc)
            .collection('photos')
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    const imageRef = firebaseStorageRef.child(doc.data().path);
                    imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(data => photos.push(
                        {id: doc.id, link: data}
                    ))
                })
            });

        console.log(photos); //This shows the array in the debugger
        photos.map((item,key) => console.log(item)); //Nothing executes in this line
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a larger code snippet of what your issue is? There isn't enough detail here to answer your question.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Do you run the map inside a component? Where do you run the map? What's meant to trigger that line of code to run? Show me that line in context of where it is being implemented.

Comment: I am executing map in the same function that i get the information from firebase. This function is in a class that extends Component. I am going to create a List from some View elements in the same function and return that list to render method.

Comment: So you're saying that after the `imageRef.getDownloadURL...` line of code you can run `console.log(photos)` and you get a result of `photos` and if you do `photos.map((item,key) => console.log(item.id))` after that console log and you get nothing?

Comment: Yes and i realize something interesting when i try to reach the photos[0] it says undefined and photos.length gives 0. I am so confused.

Comment: Could you please show me the code with the `photos.map` in where you use it? Currently you're showing me two separate things. I can't help you if you isolate everything.

Also please include the code where you're logging the full array. So that I have something to work with.

Comment: I edited to question and add the full function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code fragment `imageRef.getDownloadURL().then` because this promise not wait in each iteration and set the forEach as async is not solution.

Try this code, which should solve your problem.

```
getPhotos = async () => {
    var firebaseStorageRef = await firebase.storage().ref();
    const photoPromises = [];
    const documentSnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('pictures')
        .doc(this.props.route.params.tc)
        .collection('photos')
        .get();
    documentSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        photoPromises.push((async (doc) => {
            const imageRef = firebaseStorageRef.child(doc.data().path);
            const link = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
            return { id: doc.id, link };
        })(doc));
    });

    console.log(photoPromises); //This shows the array in the debugger
    const photos = await Promise.all(photoPromises);
    photos.map((item, key) => console.log(item)); //Nothing executes in this line
}

getPhotos();
```

Comment: This is what i needed. I was so confused for hours. Apparently i need to learn more about await async and promises. Thank you so much it works! I am accepting as an answer.